# PYTHON - Changing very small numbers as string to float (scientific notation)

Tags: python, string, format, scientific-notation

i have a string like '0.00008400' and i just want to turn it 0.00008400 (float). But python changes it to scientific notation type and it is looking like 8.4e-05,

```
float('0.00008400') = 8.4e-05 #as float
```

I saw some formatting answers but they are turning it to string instead of float.

```
format(8.4e-05, '.8f') = 0.00008400 #as string
```

and of course I can't turn this string value into float again...

```
#stupid alert
float(format(8.4e-05, '.8f')) = 8.4e-05
```

I just want to my string type input to turn float exactly...

```
'0.00008400' => 0.00008400 #string to float
```

Thanks in advance...

Edit:
there is a function that I want to use gets float value but can't understand scientific notion format of float. So this is why I want to show this float normal.
SORRY:
string format is okay too. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scientific representation is "just" a representation of your float, that does not change the real value of the float, whatever how python display it.

So I don't understand what you want to do. Could you send more informations ?

Comment: Edit:
there is a function that I want to use gets float value but can't understand scientific notion format of float. So this is why I want to show this float normal.

Comment: This has the gist of it; the displayed values are all equivalent and just vary in the structure of the output.. it's stored as an IEEE 754 double https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: I think it is not the real problem because, as I said previously, representation does not affect the value. Probably you use the wrong variable in your function input. Could you send  a minimal working example where there is the problem ?